# Linux script while loop "-a"

Tags: linux, unix

I have a nice .cgi file that I'm trying to work through but I'm not entirely sure what this "-a" does for the loop. Here is the code

```
while [ "$num" -lt 10 -a "$return_val" = 0 ]
do
    return_val='home/aaaserver/viscaClient [hex]'
    num=$(( $num + 1 ))
    sleep 3
done
```

-lt is the upper range - in this case 10 - right? What does the -a mean in this context? My guess is its "and" but just want to make sure. My Google-fu is weak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your guess is right.

See `man [`:

> ```
> EXPRESSION1 -a EXPRESSION2
>     both EXPRESSION1 and EXPRESSION2 are true
> ```

Also

> ```
> INTEGER1 -lt INTEGER2
>     INTEGER1 is less than INTEGER2
> ```

Comment: Thanks! I'm a relative linux newbie. I attempted while --help, while /?, while -h and help while but I didn't know you could use man for that. Will do from now on.

Comment: `help` works for keywords and builtins in bash, e.g. `help while` or `help echo`. `man bash` contains all the information `help` contains and much more.